# Client-side Socket.emit not working in Flask-Socketio application

Tags: javascript, flask, websocket, socket.io

I'm building a chatroom application using Flask Socketio and have run into some issues. I want to create a button that will allow the user to post a message and then save that message in a specific chatroom on the backend (no databases). Posting via the 'send to general' handler works, but sending to a specific room doesn't. In fact, the emit does not work at all for that event handler. My code is below.

Server-side:

```
import os
import json

from flask import Flask
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, emit, join_room, leave_room
from flask import Flask, session, render_template, request, redirect, url_for, g



app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["SECRET_KEY"] = os.getenv("SECRET_KEY")
socketio = SocketIO(app)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    socketio.run(app)

rooms = {

"General":[]

}

roomslist = []

#send message to the active chat
@socketio.on('send to general')
def post(data):
    message = data["message"]
    rooms["General"].append(message)
    emit("post message", {"message":message}, broadcast = True)


@socketio.on('send to room')
def send_to_room(data):
    message = data["message"]
    rooms[data["room"]] = []
    roomslist.append(str(data["rooms"]))
    emit("post message", {"message":message})
```

Client-side code:

```
    //post message to the active room
  post.onclick = () => {
    var message = document.querySelector('#user_message').value;
    var room = document.querySelector('.active').id
    if (room == "General") {
      socket.emit('send to general', {"message":message})
    }
    else if (room !== "General") {
      socket.emit('send to room', {"room":room});
    }

  })
//socket.on instances here ________________________________________

//posts messages
//does not yet post to a specific channel
  socket.on('post message', data => {
    const li = document.createElement('li');
    const username = localStorage.getItem('name');
    li.innerHTML = `${username}: ${data.message}`;
    document.querySelector('#messages').append(li);
    document.querySelector('#user_message').value = "";

  });
```

Thank you so much for helping!

Comment: I could see, you are not emitting any message in `socket.emit('send to room', {"room":room});`.

Comment: Suggestion : As a part of good programming practice, keep the `if` condition and `socketio.run(app)` part at the end of the program.

Comment: @ngShravil.py thank you! I removed the message variable from the 'send to room' handler bc the handler was not taking multiple pieces of data. Even when I add {"message":message}, the problem persists.

Comment: I am having same issue rn, were u able to resolve this? @independentvariable